# How to return the separator using split in Python?

Tags: python, split

How to return the separator when using split?

For example, `re.split('123|456', 'abc123xyz456mnp')` returns `['abc', 'xyz', 'mnp']` and `['123', '456]`.

Any function to do it?

Comment: Why should it return `['123', '456']` if you split the string by `'123'` or `'456'`?

Comment: You anyway know the separator right? `"123|456".split("|")`

Comment: Do you mean you want to find out which separator is used? something like `abc123xyz123mnp` return `['abc', 'xyz', 'mnp']` and `['123']`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot return the pattern(separator) in a different list, but you can get it with the returned list by using capturing parenthesis and than parse the list to extract the separator.
In your case using:

```
re.split(r'(123|456)', 'abc123xyz456mnp')
```

will give:

```
['abc', '123', 'xyz', '456', 'mnp']
```